# I do not want to show form's label in html

Tags: python, django

I do not want to show form's label in html.
I wrote in forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   keyword = forms.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=100)
```

in views.py

```
def index(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

in index.html

```
<div>
      <form action="{% url 'app:search' %}" method="POST">
         <table>
         {{ form|as_bootstrap }}
         </table>
         <input type="image" src="{% static 'app/box.png' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
      </form>
</div>
```

When I run the app, form’s label’s keyword is shown. I do not want to show it. What is wrong in my code?
I read `as_p` delete form’s label, so I rewrote the codes,

```
{{ form.as_p|as_bootstrap }}
```

But it is still same. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[`as_p`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) will not remove label, it just render label/input pair inside `<p>` tag. To set empty label you can use field's [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#label) argument:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   keyword = forms.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=100, label='')
```